# Jenkins 'Trigger/call builds on other projects' with current project version

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

After my build finishs (project1) i want to trigger another build (project2) adding the project version of project1 as parameter.

For this purpose i am using Jenkins build step 'Trigger/call builds on other projects'.

I configured the follwing as predefined parameters:

[image]

The result is that project.one.version is set to the project version of project2 instead of project1. It seems the property is not dissolved during the first build but during the second.

Any suggestions handling this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can share any data (i.e. job build parameters) between build as I`ve described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21145228/1361089) using [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that is the plugin which i am already using. 

I try to pass the project.version property which is resolved via Maven from project 1 to project 2 but the project.version which arrives at project 2 is the version of project 2. It seems that the property is dissolved by Maven in the build of project 2 and not passed from project 1. But that is just a guess.

Comment: I can guest, that parameter is being passed as a plain text. This plugin, AFAIK, allows you to use a file from workspace to transfer parameters for downstream build. You can try to prepare such file as a build-step (with plaintext contents) and use it

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14567842) for similar question. You can try the "Pass a variable" section for your case.

The difference seems to be that you are using the curly brackets. If that fails again try with artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select option "this project is parameterized" in project2 with string as parameter. Then use the provided variable in project2.