# How to ensure same git checkout for build and deploy jobs in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, I have a "Build" job setup to poll my git repo and automatically build on change.    Then, I have separate "Deploy to DEV", "Deploy to QA", etc. jobs that will call an Ant build that deploys appropriately.  Currently, this configuration works great.

However, this process favors deploying the latest build on the latest development branch.  I use the Copy Artifact plugin to allow the user to choose which build to deploy.  Also, the Ant scripts for build/deploy are part of the repo and are subject to change.  This means it's possible the artifact could be incompatible between versions.  So, it's ideal that I ensure that the build and deploy jobs are run using the same git checkout.

Is there an easier way?  It ought to be possible for the Deploy job to obtain the git checkout hash used from the selected build and checkout.  However, I don't see any options or plugins that do this.

Any ideas on how to simplify this configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to do this for you. The straight way is to prepare file with parameters as a build step and pass this parameters to the downstream job using the plugin. You can pass git revision as a parameter for example or other settings.

Comment: I don't want to trigger an automatic deployment, though.  For instance, I need to revert Dev to a legacy version.  I run the Deploy job, specify the build number as a "Build selector for Copy Artifact" parameter.  Copy Artifact pulls down the appropriate artifact.  However, the job doesn't automatically know to switch to the git revision that the artifact was created in.  So for now, I have a GitBranch parameter where I specify the corresponding branch.  I would like to eliminate the GitBranch parameter, really.  It should already know the revision from the build.

Comment: this way you can add some configuration files to your artifact set. Than you can use them to tell git which revision belongs to fetched artifact

Comment: I see, but how do you get the job to Copy Artifacts (to obtain this properties file) and read the properties file before the git checkout?  The checkout happens before any build steps.

Comment: I see two ways. First - try to use parameters in the git settings (I think plugins like Parametrized Build should do this for you). Second - manually checkout git as a build step. Also you can create two Jobs - one to fetch artifacts and second to be triggered with these artifacts

Answer (score 1):

The details would vary for a Git repo (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13117975/466874), but for our SVN-based jobs, what we do is have the build job (re)create an SVN tag (with a static name like "LatestSuccessfulBuild") at successful completion, and then we configure the deployment jobs to use that tag as their repo URL rather than the trunk location. This ensures that deployments are always of whatever revision was successfully built by the build job (meaning all unit tests passed, etc.) rather than allowing newer trunk commits to sneak into the deployment build.